# Custom Attribute Not Disabled on Bulk Update Attributes

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, magento2.2.3, simple-product

I have a custom attribute named container that is a select field. When I use Update Attributes to update multiple products at once this container attribute is always enabled even though I haven't checked the Change box underneath it and when I update attributes it actually gets saved. This attribute is for simple products. I've also noticed that when I edit a configurable product it's not disabled there either.

I have another size attribute that works just fine so I'm not sure what the difference is. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. You can't have a custom attribute code named "container" because Magento uses that css class already in the page. I renamed my attribute code in the eav_attribute table to item-container and everything is good now.